# How does HERE maps 3D work with its heightmaps?

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl, here-api, heightmap

I have seen the work of HERE Maps 3D, which uses WebGL:

[image]

live demo: http://here.com/45.4382049,12.3281023,18.51,124,75,3d.day

It's look like, that it's a technique similar to the heghtmaps.

I wonder, how does it work, exactly for building extruding from textures. I have looked at network in browser tools to look at requests/responses, and have seen the next:

[image]

The goes two files, the texture file and some binary `*.n3m` file, which has a relation to the tile texture with similar `x, y, zoom` values.

Also I've look how texture is looked like, and understand, that it's not a standard aerial (cosmos) view:

[image]

You can see some gray pixels in it, and that tile texture has both some view from cosmos and some textures for buildings, and these all exist in one texture file.

I think, that HERE maps technique is not just awesome, but super fantastic. If some award similar to OSCAR exist, but for IT-industry, developers from HERE maps must have such an award.

But, let's return to the main topic. I want to know, what exact technique do they use? Maybe it's very popular technique, which is well known? If so, please tell me some information about it.

I've successfully created a three.js application, which is creating beautiful terrain from a heightmaps of the real world, so when I've seen such a sample from HERE maps I want to try to make the same.

So, questions are:

- what is a technique of this sample (as understanded it has common in heightmaps extruding technique)?
- why textures are generated so?
- what can you tell about `*.n3m` file format (it's a binary one, I'm trying to search information about it in Google search, but the most interesting is next: http://content.stamen.com/files/idiocode/index.html)?

Related links:

- http://techbeyond.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/nokia-3d-webgl-map-experiments/
- https://github.com/migurski/NokiaWebGL
- http://content.stamen.com/files/idiocode/index.html

Comment: Isn't it the same than Google Earth ?

Comment: @vals It's the same about functionality like F4Maps it uses WebGL and doesn't require any additional plugin to be installed, also as I think there some differences in each implementation of showing building data, etc...

Comment: If you don't know about Chrome canvas inspector, take a look at http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/05/debugging-with-chromes-canvas-inspection/

Comment: By the way, in some shaders I have seen a line like //#define SHOW_HEIGHTMAP   (commented), but I haven't seen it uncommented

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it doesn't use a height map. It's just 3d geometry data. The images you see are simply texture maps